# How many transactions per second Postgresql supports

Tags: postgresql

Is there are any documented details on what is the maximum transactions per second Postgresql can perform (transaction (begin-----end)

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm... that's pretty much a "how long is a piece of string" question. :-)

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? We have no idea what kind of hardware you have and what kind of things you do inside your transactions. Every answer about X tps is correct and it's correct for every kind of database brand as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TPS will depend enormously on

- Hardware
- What you are actually doing in the transaction

You can get an idea of the relative perfomance of various RDBMS comparisons at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_Processing_Performance_Council